# Who is going or who are going?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which one is correct if I am asking about a group of people that someone is going to meet?

I know that the it should depend if the following word is on singular or plural, but on this case I am not sure as "who is going to the PLACE A" has no indication of plural or singular.
Who is going feels right.... but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Who is going" is correct. In some parts of the US, it's not uncommon for people to say "Who all is going."

Hope that helps.